# Differences in mean curvatures for permuted coordinates of a manifold

Tags: differential-geometry, curvature

Below is an example demonstrating the differences in mean curvatures and one other quantity, and below is my question. Please comment if you need me to explain in more detail or clarify notation, or if there are any mistakes.

**Example 1**
Consider the manifold with coordinates given by
$$(x,y,x+y, x^2).$$
At each point, there are two unit normal vectors
$$n_1 = \frac{\sqrt{3}}{3} [1, 1, -1, 0]^T$$
and
$$n_2 = \frac{\sqrt{3}}{3\sqrt{8x^2+3}} [4x,-2x,2x,-3].$$
The vector of mean curvatures in the directions of each of these normals is given by
$$c=\left[0, -\frac{2\sqrt{3}}{(8x^2+3)^{3/2}}\right]^T.$$
Further, if we let $q$ be the vector with components $q^r = \operatorname{Tr}{N (Dn_r) N^T}$ where $Dn_r$ is the Jacobian derivative of the vector $n_r$, $r=1,2$ and $N$ is the matrix with $r$-th row equal to $n_r$, then we get that $q=\vec{0}$.

Brownian motion on this manifold has drift $\mu =N^T(q+c)$, i.e.
$$\mu = \frac{1}{(8x^2+3)^2}[-8x, 4x, -4x, 6]^T.$$

**Example 2**
Now, permute the last two coordinates so that instead we have
$$(x,y,x^2,x+y).$$
Now, we can obtain unit normal vectors
$$n_1 = \frac{1}{\sqrt{4x^2+1}} [2x,0,-1,0]^T,$$
$$n_2 = \frac{1}{\sqrt{(4x^2+1)(8x^2+3)}}\left[1, 4x^2+1, 2x, -(4x^2+1)\right]^T,$$
mean curvature vector $c$,
$$c=\left[-\frac{1}{(4x^2+1)^{3/2}}, -\frac{2x(16x^2+5)}{(4x^2+1)^{3/2}(8x^2+3)^{3/2}}\right]^T$$
and now a *non-zero* $q$, as defined above,
$$q=\frac{1}{\sqrt{(4x^2+1)(8x^2+3)}}\left[\frac{1}{(4x^2+1)\sqrt{8x^2+3}}, -\frac{2x}{4x^2+1}\right]^T$$
and drift of a Brownian motion
$$\mu = \frac{1}{(8x^2+3)^2}[-8x, 4x, -4x, 6]^T,$$
again from $\mu=N^T(q+c)$.

**My questions**:

1. Why are the mean curvatures different for these two permutations of coordinates of, essentially, the same manifold? (From a probabilist perspective, I get the same SDE for Brownian motion on both manifolds--this might be a blasphemous viewpoint to differential geometers, so please excuse my ignorance!)
2. What is the geometric interpretation of $q^r = \operatorname{Tr}(N (D n_r)N^T)$ and why does it change depending on the permutation of coordinates (or rather on the order of orthonormalizing the rows of $Df$ where $f(x,y,z,w)=0$ defines the manifold, via component definitions e.g. $f^1(x,y,z,w)=x+y-z$ and and $f^2(x,y,z,w)=x^2-w$) for the first presentation.

Comment: The manifold is 4D with coords (x, y, x+y, x2) or (x, y, x2, x+y). There are two unit norm vectors, n1 and n2.
The mean curvature vector c has components given by c=[c1,c2]T where c1 and c2 are expressions involving x and possibly other constants.
There is a vector q defined using the Jacobian derivative of the normal vectors. In Example 1, q=0 while in Example 2 q is non-zero with components given in the example.
The drift μ of Brownian motion on the manifold is given by μ=NT(q+c) where N is a matrix with row r equal to nr. The expressions for μ are given in the examples. Is this correct?

Comment: @AnonImus Yup that is the gist of the setup.

Comment: Because the surface has codimension $2$, there is a *circle* of unit normal vectors at each point, thus a family of second fundamental forms parametrized by a circle. You are choosing random orthogonal pairs from that circle. Why didn't you choose the second $n_1$ and $n_2$ just by switching the last two coordinates? Up to an orientation issue, the mean curvature vector should be a well-defined vector, if you keep track of an ambient isometry such as you are using.

Answer (score 3):

Here's the way I compute this as a differential geometer. I differentiate the parametrization, not the normal vector, to arrive at the second fundamental form. With the parametrization
$$g(x,y)=(x,y,x+y,x^2),$$
I get $g_x = (1,0,1,2x)$ and $g_y = (0,1,1,0)$ spanning the tangent space, with corresponding orthonormal normal vectors
$$N_1 = \frac1{\sqrt3}(1,1,-1,0) \quad\text{and}\quad N_2 = \frac1{\sqrt{9+24x^2}}(4x,-2x,2x,-3).$$ You and I have chosen the same normal vectors.
The corresponding second fundamental forms are
$$\text{II}_j = \begin{bmatrix} g_{xx}\cdot N_j & g_{xy}\cdot N_j \\ g_{yx}\cdot N_j & g_{yy}\cdot N_j\end{bmatrix},$$
and so the second-fundamental form is the vector-valued $2$-tensor
$$\text{II}_1\otimes N_1 + \text{II}_2\otimes N_2 = \begin{bmatrix} 0 & 0\\0 & 0\end{bmatrix} \otimes N_1 + \frac{-6}{\sqrt{9+24x^2}}\begin{bmatrix} 1 & 0\\0 & 0\end{bmatrix} \otimes N_2.$$
The mean-curvature vector will be
$$H=\text{tr}(\text{II}_1)N_1 + \text{tr}(\text{II}_2)N_2 = \frac{-6}{\sqrt{9+24x^2}}N_2 = \frac{-2}{3+8x^2}(4x,-2x,2x,-3).$$
This seems to agree with your result.

If I change the surface, as you did, by switching the final two coordinates, those two coordinates switch in everything I've computed and nothing else changes; I end up with $H'=\dfrac{-2}{3+8x^2}(4x,-2x,-3,2x)$. I continue not to understand what you've done. Why did you choose such arcane normal vectors now? Why didn't you just choose the corresponding normal vectors in the first case and compare the mean-curvature vectors with the two different orthonormal bases?

Comment: Insightful! The arcane choice of normal vectors was due to (perhaps too blindly!) following a recipe for Brownian motion simulations on a manifold. (Essentially, you have a Stratonoivch SDE $dX_t = P(X_t)\circ dW_t$ where $P(x)$ is the orthogonal projection onto $T_xM$. For codimension $1$, we nicely get the Ito drift as as $c(x)n(x)$ where $c$ is the mean curvature in the direction of the normal vector $n$. For higher codimension, I obtained $N^T(c+q)$ as the Ito drift, where $c$ is a mean-curvature vector now, showed that $q=0$ for hypersurfaces, and found choices where $q\neq 0$ and $q=0$.)

Answer (score -1):

Question 1: The mean curvature measures the average deviation of the surface from its tangent planes, and it depends on the normal vectors and their derivatives. In Example 1, the normal vectors have a specific form that is different from Example 2, and this difference in normal vectors leads to different mean curvature vectors. Essentially, the way the surface deviates from its tangent planes is different for the two examples due to the different normal vectors.

Provided your probabilistic perspective, the SDE for Brownian motion only depends on the Riemannian metric of the manifold, which is the same for both examples. However, the drift term of the SDE, which depends on the mean curvature, is different for the two examples due to the difference in normal vectors and mean curvature vectors.

Comment: "However, the drift term of the SDE, which depends on the mean curvature, is different for the two examples due to the difference in normal vectors and mean curvature vectors." Actually my examples and computations in the OP show that the drift, $\mu$, is *the same for both choices* despite the normal vectors, mean curvatures and $q$ being different. Perhaps you skimmed the OP too quickly?